# How do I revert to default with KOMAoptions?

Tags: koma-script

In the middle of a document I have to set a landscape with double column, I tried with `\begin{landscape}` and `\begin{multicols}{2}`, but for certain tables this approach didn't work. After some research, I came across `KOMAoptions`, which works as intended. I used it as follows:

```
\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,paper=landscape,twocolumn,pagesize}
```

However, after I use it in the intended page, I don't know how to get back to the default configuration.

I have tried enclosing with curly brackets

```
{
\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,paper=landscape,twocolumn,pagesize}

}
```

but `KOMAoptions` doesn't affect the layout.

Resetting with `\KOMAoptions` doesn't work either

```
# normal content
\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,paper=landscape,twocolumn,pagesize}
# double columned landscaped content

\KOMAoptions{paper=A4}
# normal content
```

since `\KOMAoptions{paper=A4}` still keeps the layout to double column and landscape.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: There is no MWE in the question. So I do not know, if there are other options changed or `geometry` is loaded and used.

You can `paper=landscape` revert by `paper=portrait` and `twocolumn=true` by `twocolumn=false`.

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\cleardoublepage
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,twocolumn=true}
\lipsum[1-12]
\cleardoublepage
\KOMAoptions{paper=portrait,twocolumn=false}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that changing the paper orientation with `\KOMAoptions` does not automatically recalculate the type area. But using option `twocolumn` after loading `typearea` (done by the KOMA-Script class) will automatically recalculate the type area using `\recalctypearea`. So you should change the paper orientation before using option `twocolumn`. If you change this order you have to add `\recalctypearea` after `\KOMAoptions`.

Comment: @user3889486 Does this answer solve your issue? Then you can accept it.